# Bootstrap Navbar toggle with collapsed button not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, bootstrap-4, navbar

I made this button  When the screen is minimized, such as in the phone but it cannot be pressed when the screen is minimized What can I do to make this button can be pressed??

This is my code that ive tried

```
<script src="../assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="../assets/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

<script src="../assets/js/popper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../assets/css/paper-kit.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../assets/css/paper-dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

---

```
<button  type="button" class="navbar-toggler"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" >
    <span class="navbar-toggler-bar navbar-kebab"></span>
    <span class="navbar-toggler-bar navbar-kebab"></span>
    <span class="navbar-toggler-bar navbar-kebab"></span>
</button>


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
```

---

I wrote this code in Site.Masterpage

Comment: you need to give us more than that, are you using the developer console? are any errors happening at any time?

Comment: What is Site.Masterpage?